# I can't run mysql on xampp after windows shutting down by self

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I got a problem in starting mysql (xampp). The mysql can't run after my windows shutting down by self.

I think the problem is because some file not complete before windows is shutting down. But I don't know where is the file. Or may be another problem ?

Although the apache can't run too. Please help

Anyone please help for this problem

[image: Error messages picture]

#### Error messages

```
2015-05-25 21:42:44 3776 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.

2015-05-25 21:42:44 c78 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.

2015-05-25 21:42:44 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages


2015-05-25 21:42:44 3776 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled

2015-05-25 21:42:44 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions

2015-05-25 21:42:44 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used

2015-05-25 21:42:44 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3

2015-05-25 21:42:44 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions

2015-05-25 21:42:44 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M

2015-05-25 21:42:44 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

2015-05-25 21:42:45 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.

2015-05-25 21:42:45 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 17355383

2015-05-25 21:42:45 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!

2015-05-25 21:42:45 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.

2015-05-25 21:42:45 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...

2015-05-25 21:42:47 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 

2015-05-25 21:42:47 3776 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 17355393

2015-05-25 21:42:49 3776 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.

2015-05-25 21:42:49 3776 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start

2015-05-25 21:42:49 3776 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.20 started; log sequence number 17355393

2015-05-25 21:42:49 3776 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306

2015-05-25 21:42:49 3776 [Note] IPv6 is available.

2015-05-25 21:42:49 3776 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';

2015-05-25 21:42:49 3776 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why this problem comes. But to resolve this you can:

1. Get backup of `xampp` > `htdocs` and `xampp` > `mysql` > `data` folders in some-other location away from `xampp` folder.
2. Uninstall `xampp` and re-install it back.
3. Replace copied folders `htdocs` and `data` in respective folders of newly installed `xampp` folder.

Now you can run `apache` and `mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

1. exit Xampp server
2. go to your C:\xampp\mysql\data
3. delete the ibdata1 file
4. restart xampp server

Make sure that skype is not running during this process.

It should work